# Enable "Ship to a different address" only for specific products in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, checkout

I want to disable (hide) 'Ship to a different address' for most of the products and enable it only for specific (couple of) products. I have used `add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', '__return_false');` but it disables 'Ship to a different address' section of all the products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a similar code to your other question:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', 'disable_checkout_shipping_address');
function disable_checkout_shipping_address( $needs_shipping_address ) {

    $products_ids = array(793, 796);
    $found = $others_found = false;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if (in_array( $cart_item['data']->get_id(), $products_ids ) ){
            $found = true;
        } else {
            $others_found = true;
        }
    }

    if( $found && ! $others_found )
        $needs_shipping_address = true;
    else
        $needs_shipping_address = false;

    return $needs_shipping_address;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).